# привязать modal к клавишам

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здрасьте. Вообщем меня интересует возможность привязки модального окна к клавишам виртуальной клавиатуры, не вставляя кусок самого кода модального окна к каждой клавише. Поясню, что сейчас имею ввиду:

Есть кусок кода:

```
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F3"><i class="a">F3</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F4"><i class="a">F4</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F5"><i class="a">F5</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F6"><i class="a">F6</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F7"><i class="a">F7</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F8"><i class="a">F8</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F9"><i class="a">F9</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F10"><i class="a">F10</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F11"><i class="a">F11</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="key" data-key="F12"><i class="a">F12</i></a>
```

К каждой клавише привязывается модальное окно. Допустим, это F3:

```
    <a href="#modal-center" class="key" data-key="F3" uk-toggle><i class="a">F3</i>
    <div id="modal-center" class="uk-flex-top " uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body uk-margin-auto-vertical  uk-alert-primary">
    <button class="uk-modal-close-default" type="button" uk-close></button>
    <p>123</p>
</div>
```

Вот и встает вопрос, есть ли другой способ привязки модального окна к клавише не вставляя этот кусок кода в код каждой клавиши?

В принципе, ничего страшного в этом нет, просто интересен другой более легкий и менее громоздкий способ решения этой задачи.

Comment: Ну, тут же всё зависит от того, какой контент Вы хотите видеть в модальном окне, открывая его разными клавишами. Скорее всего, разный. Значит, Вам надо либо делать столько же разных окон с разным содержимым, сколько и клавиш. Либо динамически выводить контент в модальное окно - в зависимости от того, какая клавиша нажата. Поясните задачу.

Comment: Контент на всех клавишах будет идентичный, спс за что напомнили мне про этот важный пункт.

Comment: Тогда вообще непонятно, в чём проблема: делаете одно окно с id="modal-center" пишете в каждой ссылке адрес href="#modal-center", и при нажатии на любую клавишу у Вас будет открываться модальное окно.

Comment: :)))) Нет слов, как я не смог додуматься до этого. Видимо в голове мусора много :). Спасибо за ответ! :)